# On non-principal Ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Claim: A family of sets A of S can be extended to a non-rpincipal ultrafilter iff every finite family of A has as an intersection an infinite set.

(1) I have been trying to prove this by showing that every set of A is infinite.

Then I argue that every finite collection of set belonging to A have the finite intersection property. So $A_1,  \cap ..., \cap A_n = X  \neq \emptyset$. Since $X \in U$ we have immediatley that X is infinite by (1).    |Does this make sense ?

Comment: You seem to be arguing about the trivial direction. By the way, if $S$ is infinite, any cofinite member of $A$ is infinite. So, mentioning "cofinite" in (1) is redundant - and irrelevant.

Comment: Right! Can you give me a hint for the proof strategy of the other direction ?

Comment: Use the axiom of choice.

Comment: Right ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your family of sets $\mathscr{A}$ as a base of a filter $\mathscr{F}$ on $S$, that is, define $$\mathscr{F} = \{B\subseteq S\colon B\supseteq A\text{ for some }A\in \mathscr{A}\}.$$
(Check that this is a filter indeed.) Now use the Kuratowski-Zorn lemma to argue that $\mathscr{F}$ is contained in some maximal filter (ultrafilter).

Comment: Awesome Tomek!!Thanks!